# Shorten proposition with abbreviations in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Imagine the following theorem:

```
 assumes d: "distinct (map fst zs_ws)"
 assumes e: "(p :: complex poly) = lagrange_interpolation_poly zs_ws"
 shows "degree p ≤ (length zs_ws)-1 ∧
         (∀ x y. (x,y) ∈ set zs_ws ⟶ poly p x = y)"
```

I would like to eliminate the second assumption, without having to substitute the value of p on each occurrence. I did this in proofs with the let command:

```
let ?p = lagrange_interpolation_poly zs_ws
```

But it doesn't work in the theorem statement. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a local definition in the lemma statement like this:

```
lemma l:
  fixes zs_ws
  defines "p == lagrange_interpolation_poly zs_ws"
  assumes d: "distinct (map fst zs_ws)"
  shows "degree p ≤ (length zs_ws)-1 ∧ (∀(x,y) ∈ set zs_ws. poly p x = y)"
```

The definition gets unfolded when the proof is finished. So when you look at `thm l` later, all occurrences of `p` have been substituted by the right-hand side. Inside the proof, `p_def` refers to the definining equation for `p` (what you call `e`). The `defines` clause is most useful when you want to control in the proof when Isabelle's proof tools just see `p` and when they see the expanded right-hand side.